Geometry Nodes: How Can I make an Organic Vein system?
I want to make a geometry system that takes the volume of a mesh and first makes a bunch of sphere instances in the volume (these are stars) then the system makes pathways and organic vein-like connections between these stars. Id like the system to also encapsulate the stars. The result will look similar to 3d renderings of neurons.
I found a video similar to this on YouTube, a tutorial to make a system inspired by the Plexus After Effects plug-in.
Here are some images of the system I have already set up, as well as inspiration pics. I have tried adding curves and organic textures but nothing actually affects the lines.






3D grid of connected neighbors


Distort


Remove half of the longest connections


Remove all but the biggest island


Add thickness
Convert curves to mesh by giving it a circular profile, fillet the curve first with small radius to remove profile stretching at sharp angles, cover connections with spheres, give the spheres bigger radius than curve profile to make soma (cell body) more chunky:


Remesh


Smooth


Add wrinkles and material


Shader


Black world


Cycles

Some further ideas: base ball (joint) size on number/length of connections, extrude from the balls (after remesh) to form dendrites, the dendrites could also be formed by a bigger 3D grid of connected edges and "shortest path" functionality, light neurons up from inside, perhaps use a shortest path functionality to light up a particular path through the network, make the network bigger, for cycles adjust subsurface distance to keep the outer neurons dark so they merge with the background and give an impression of taking a photo of a small part of a bigger network.
